# UPDATE query works fine when run from Access, but raises SQL syntax error from within C# app

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, sql-update

I have a very simple Update statement that will update mail server settings and network credentials info... Query works fine when I run it in Access but C# keeps giving me the error stating that my SQL Syntax is wrong ... I have a dataaccess layer (dal class) and Update instance method pasted belows ... But the problem must be sth else cuz I have updated lots of stuff this way but this time it just won't do .. any clues will be greatly appreciated. Thx in advance.

Update instance method in DAL class .. (this is supposed to be a Data Access Layer :) I'm just a management graduate :P

```
public int UpdateRow(string Query, bool isSP, params OleDbParameter[] args)
{
    int affectedRows = -1;
    using (con = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = Query;
            if (isSP)
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            }
            if (args != null)
            {
                foreach (OleDbParameter prm in args)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
                }
            }

            try
            {
            con.Open();
            affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(OleDbException ex)
            {
            throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
    return affectedRows;
}
```

And the ASP.NEt codebehind that will do the updating =

```
protected void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
DAL dal = new DAL();
string upt = string.Format("UPDATE [MailConfig] SET Server='{0}', Username='{1}', Password='{2}', AddressFrom='{3}', DisplayName='{4}'",server.Text,username.Text,password.Text,replyto.Text,displayname.Text);
dal.UpdateRow(upt,false,null);
LoadData();
}
```

peace!

Comment: Never do thi! : catch(OleDbException ex) { throw ex; }

Always throw new Exception with "ex" in "InnerException" or use simple "throw;" withow "ex". In your way, you loose ale information about callstack etc...

Comment: Could you paste the data types of the rows being updated, as well as the data type of each object?

Comment: @TcKs This is very good advice! If you throw ex, you run the risk of loosing the origional ex further up the chain.

Answer (score 3):

Trying wrapping your field names in [ ]. I have had problems in the past with certain field names such as a username and password and count, etc, being recognized as reserved words and screwing up the sql giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

First off - don't use `string.Format` here. Use parameters, and add parameters to the command. Right now, you are wide open to SQL injection attacks. Think "[Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)".

Re "stating that my SQL Syntax is wrong" - can you please quote the exact error?

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to catch an exception just to throw it - just let it bubble itself upwards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you  have no where clause in your Update, so it will update all rows, and violate key constraints causing an error, if you have any.

Second, running that kind of code makes you very vunerable to SQL Injection, if someone enters a username that has a sql command embedded in it, you could lose all your data.

You should use parameterized queries. You specify your parameters in the sql command with @paramname instead of using {4}, and then with the command object do accessCommand.parameters.AddWithValue("@paramname", value)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a CommandType of StoredProcedure, but your query is not a stored procedure name, its a sql query without a where clause.

```
UPDATE [MailConfig] 
SET Server='{0}', 
    Username='{1}', 
    Password='{2}', 
    AddressFrom='{3}', 
    DisplayName='{4}'"
```

So you need to remove the command type line, or change it to a correct command type CommandType.Text, and add a Where clause specifying what rows are to be affected.

I don't think Access even has Stored Procedures, so there's no using to use that command type with it.

An example of a command that does use stored procedures would be something like:

```
string sqlCommString = "QCApp.dbo.ColumnSeek";
SqlCommand metaDataComm = new SqlCommand(sqlCommString, sqlConn);
metaDataComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

The command string for that type is just the name of the stored proc.